# What are the advantages of using name vs id in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<input type ="button" name="buttonsel" id="buttonse1"/>
```

`$("#buttonse1")` VS `$("[name=buttonse1]")`

What are the advantages in using name and id in jquery

Comment: @roXon is that the only one advantage between name and id

Comment: sure not, you can group radio buttons with `name` remember?

Comment: It's another comparison of apples with oranges

Comment: @roXon can u briefly explain in answer column with the advantages of both

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT**

- The names in name= must be unique within a form. The names in id= must be unique within the entire document.
- JavaScript needed unique names, but there were too many documents already out here without unique name= names, so the W3 people invented the id tag that was required to be unique. Unfortunately older browsers did not understand it. So you need both naming schemes in your forms.

check full details over here : http://mindprod.com/jgloss/htmlforms.html#IDVSNAME

---

Id can able to indentify element unique.

valid html contains unique id for each element.

```
<input type ="button" name="buttonsel" id="buttonse1"/>
<input type ="button" name="buttonsel" id="newbutton"/>//valid for both id and name
<input type ="button" name="buttonsel" id="buttonse1"/>//not valid as id repeated but name is valid even if repeated
```

But you can give same name to multiple items that might not able find element unequally.

Comment: can u just explain with some examples!!

Comment: it can also vice versa... its not a solution in my opinion

Comment: @Pranay Rana now i understand the difference will accept ur answer

Comment: Sorry. I'm just interested in which official documentation is written that a `name` must be unique within a `<form>`? thanks.

Comment: @Christoph: avoid such minor edits in the future. It's not welcome in the community. And btw you could rather (while editing) fix the "typo" about `name` attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Selecting by ID is still faster than by names in jquery.

Comment: so there is no use of name is it

Answer (score 3):

Ok, `$("#")` versus the JS native `document.getElementById()` is slower, but it's the fastest jQuery selector you can find around. But don't bother with speed. `#` is simply `#` and there's only ONE in your DOM right?

Accessing attributes is always slower, and if we have in mind that we plan to use `name` like we're dealing with `classes` and we plan to have 1000+ elements with the same name.... than you could do some speed tests if that's your concern.

Any way your question seems a bit odd, if you already HAVE an ID, and you know that ID is *wow!* than you tell me 1 reason why not to use it? :)

Comment: just asking the advantage of it in jquery

Comment: Look, the advantage is just to KNOW what all selectors you have in play! Just use them. Your time in programming is the most valuable thing than bothering which one is the best. (Unless you should really care.) Otherwise just use the one that best suit your needs! simple.

Comment: What happens when dealing with a zero-to-many repeating block of controls?  ID's are required to be unique, but trying to individually set the ID values of multiple controls can be quite a hassle.  It can also be a hassle to correctly reference each of those controls.  Would `Name` make sense in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `id` then you will have only 1 element selected, and JS will stop looking for another if you already found one.

By using `name` in `$('[name="something"]')` you can have more than 1 elements. jQuery will look in every HTML node for `name="something"`. And `name` attribute is only valid for `input` elements (even though you can use it in other elements). Also, there can be more than one valid element with `name` attribute (for example: `<input type="radio"/>` and `<input type="checkbox"/>`).

Answer (score 1):

`ID` is unique. All HTML elements supports `ID` attributes. In jQuery, using `id` selector is faster then using `name`

`NAME` is not unique and multiple elements can share same `name`. `NAME` attributes are applicable only to `a`, `form` and `input` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, you will find that using an #id in your selector is *much* faster. See here:

http://www.componenthouse.com/jQuery-Performance-analysis-of-selectors-td20.html

Secondly, an ID on an HTML element will ensure a degree of uniqueness as opposed to using the name in your selector.